# Reading and Writing to a file simultaneously

Tags: python, file-io, system-verilog

I have a module in written in System Verilog that dumps the contents of the SRAM into a file.  I would like to read from this file and use the data in a separate program written in python, but in real time.  I don't have much control over the writing from the verilog code. Is it possible to somehow manage the two read and writes? Currently when it reads from the file, there is a (seemingly) random number inserted at the start of every line and that throws off the parsing.  I assume these prefixes only appear when they are reading and writing at the same time because if I run them both very slowly it works fine.

```
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="#000000")
canvas.pack()
img = PhotoImage(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.create_image((WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2), image=img, state="normal")

def redraw():
fp = open('test_data.txt','r')
lines=fp.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
        #do stuff
fp.close()
window.after(35,redraw)  

window.after(35,redraw)
mainloop()
```

This is what is reading.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: That seems to me like a bad idea, and you need some other way to control when one process can read data produced by another in a file -- for example by using a fifo.  The "random stuff" that you read may be caused by the fact that you're reading *lines.*  If the full content is "ab\ncd\nef\n", it's three lines; but if the partial file contains "ab\nc", it will be read as two lines, and when more comes later, the "d\nef\n" will be read as two extra lines.

Comment: How about using [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) which is a very simple standalone database.  Python speaks it natively with [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) , but you'll have to link in C/C++ code into your verilog simulator as a system task or DPI call to get Verilog to speak it.

Comment: Use files to communicate in real time sounds like a bad idea. Can you modify the SystemVerilog code to call a DPI function instead of writing to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading and writing a file from multiple processes is likely to be unpredictable.

If you are running on a Unix-like system, you could use `mkfifo` to make a file-like object which you can write to and read from simultaneously and the data will stay in the correct order.

On Windows you need a NamedPipe - which you could create from Python and then connect to by opening as a normal file in SystemVerilog (I believe!)

http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32pipe.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using VPI to directly access the contents of the SRAM straight from the simulation.  This also opens the possibility of dynamically adjusting your stimulus (e.g. sending data until a FIFO is full) rather than relying on files for input/output.

Since you're using Python you could look into [Cocotb](http://potentialventures.github.io/cocotb/), an open-source Python cosimulation framework.  Basically you can use the python 'dot' notation to traverse the design hierarchy and pull out values:

```py
# Pull out the values from the simulation
for index in range(len(dut.path.through.hierarchy.ram)):
    val = dut.path.through.hierarchy.ram[index].value.integer
    # do stuff
```

I created a quick example on EDA Playground with a simplistic example: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/57/565

*Disclaimer*: I'm one of the Cocotb developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipe, in this example a cmd (windows) command line writes in the pipe, then the program shows its output from the same pipe:

```
import subprocess,sys

p = subprocess.Popen("netsatat",shell=False ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    out = p.stdout.readline()
    if out == '' and p.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != b'':
        print(out.decode('ascii','backslashreplace'))
    else :
        break;
```