# VHDL-Textio- Reading lines from a text file which is being written on by another process

Tags: text, vhdl, read-write

I am trying to write a packet generator in my test-bench. I have to write into a file and read from it during the whole test. It seems that when I close a file after I read a line from it the pointer goes back to the first line. So I don't know how to read a file line-by-line and close it between each read. I need to somehow retain the value of the pointer even after the file is closed or remove the line after each read so that the next time the file is opened for read the second line will be read. Read requests and write are independent and they are not synced, so the read process may reach to the end of the file and it has wait before a new line is written. Write process is in append mode.
More info about the code:
 svc0 should be written every 3rd clock cycle and svc1 every 12. In the write process if the current clock is a factor of 3 or 12 it will log the current clock inside the respective file. Up-on a request (next_packet=1), one line should be read from each file and then the file should be closed(can I avoid this somehow?) for the write process (append mode) to access it if needed. The code represents two traffics.

Thank you very much

```
    library IEEE;
      use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
      use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
      use std.textio.all;
      use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
     library work;
      use work.txt_util.all;
      use work.testutil.all;
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    entity master is
       generic(    
         SVC0_USAGE           : integer := 3;
         SVC1_USAGE           : integer := 12
       );
      port(
        clk                  : in  std_logic;
        rst_n                : in  std_logic;
        en                   : in  std_logic;--;
        next_packet          : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        Clock_stamp_0:  out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        Clock_stamp_1:  out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        svc_read    :   out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
      );
    end entity;
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    architecture rtl of master is
      --Percentage
      type svc_percent_array is array(1 downto 0) of integer;
      signal svc_percent : svc_percent_array;
      --Files
      file generate_svc0 : text;
      file generate_svc1 : text;

     --Counting clocks
     signal     clk_count_c         :integer range 0 to 2000;
     signal     count               :std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
     --- read and write 
     signal svc_ready       :std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);          

    begin  
    ---------------------------------
    ---Clock counter-----------------
    ---------------------------------
     process (clk, clk_count_c) 
     variable clk_count_v : integer range 0 to 2000;
     begin 
       if (rising_edge(clk)) then  
            if rst_n='0' then 
                    clk_count_v := 0  ;
              else   
                clk_count_v := clk_count_c+1;
            end if; 
        end if;
        clk_count_c <= clk_count_v;         
    end process;     
      count <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(clk_count_c,32));

      svc_percent(0) <= SVC0_USAGE;
      svc_percent(1) <= SVC1_USAGE;


     ----------------------------------
     ----Write to  files-------
     ----------------------------------

      process(clk,count,clk_count_c)

        variable v_ILINE_0      : line;
        variable v_OLINE_0      : line;
        variable v_ILINE_1      : line;
        variable v_OLINE_1      : line;

        variable v_write_0      :integer range 0 to 2000;
        variable v_read_0       :integer range 0 to 2000;
        variable v_write_1      :integer range 0 to 2000;
        variable v_read_1       :integer range 0 to 2000;

        variable Clock_stamp_v_0    :std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        variable Clock_stamp_v_1    :std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

      begin
      file_open(generate_svc0,"svc0_gen",append_mode);  
      file_open(generate_svc1,"svc1_gen",append_mode);  

      file_close(generate_svc0);
      file_close(generate_svc1);

        if (rising_edge(clk)) then          
            if rst_n='0' then 
                svc_read <= (others => '0');            
            else
                ---------------Writing/reading clock stamps into/from generated log files---------
                for svc in 0 to 1 loop
                    case svc is 
                        when 0 => 
                            -----Write cycle----------------
                            if (clk_count_c mod SVC0_USAGE = 0) then
                                    file_open(generate_svc0,"svc0_gen",append_mode);                        
                                    write(v_OLINE_0, count, right, 32);
                                    writeline(generate_svc0, v_OLINE_0);
                                    file_close(generate_svc0);
                            end if;

                            ----read cycle-------------------
                            if ( next_packet(0) = '1' ) then  --next_packet IS SENT FROM fsm AND TELLS THE READ_PROCESS TO WAIT OR TO READ
                                file_open(generate_svc0,"svc0_gen",read_mode);
                                if not endfile(generate_svc0) then                       
                                    readline(generate_svc0, v_ILINE_0);
                                    read(v_ILINE_0,Clock_stamp_v_0);
                                    Clock_stamp_0 <= Clock_stamp_v_0;                               
                                    svc_read(0) <='1';      
                                else
                                    svc_read(0) <='0';
                                end if;
                                file_close(generate_svc0);
                            else      
                            end if;

                        when 1 =>           
                            -----Write cycle----------------
                            if (clk_count_c mod SVC0_USAGE = 0) then
                                    file_open(generate_svc1,"svc1_gen",append_mode);                        
                                    write(v_OLINE_1, count, right, 32);
                                    writeline(generate_svc1, v_OLINE_1);
                                    file_close(generate_svc1);
                            end if;

                            ----read cycle-------------------
                            if ( next_packet(1) = '1' ) then 
                                file_open(generate_svc1,"svc1_gen",read_mode);
                                if not endfile(generate_svc1) then
                                    readline(generate_svc1, v_ILINE_1);
                                    read(v_ILINE_1,Clock_stamp_v_1);

                                    Clock_stamp_1 <= Clock_stamp_v_1;
                                    svc_read(1) <='1';      
                                else
                                    svc_read(1) <='0';
                                end if;
                                file_close(generate_svc1);
                            else
                            end if;
                    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                    when others =>
                    --
                    end case;
                end loop;
            end if; --resst     
        end if; --rising edge clock
       end process;

      end architecture;
```

Comment: See the question [How to read from a specific line from a text file in VHDL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184087/how-to-read-from-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file-in-vhdl) for some possible tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Reading and Writing to a file simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992375/reading-and-writing-to-a-file-simultaneously)

Comment: Rather than struggle with making this work through file I/O consider representing your packets as records stored in a linked list. You can access it cleanly through a protected type without getting the underlying OS involved. It would eliminate the round trip through a string representation and save you from having to parse any text.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19197782/561560), VHDL has strengths and weaknesses. In my opinion, File I/O is not one of its strengths. You can read, and you can write, but doing anything with a hint of complexity can get awkward quickly.

You didn't give a solid reason as to why you need files at all. As Kevin suggested in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523139/vhdl-textio-reading-lines-from-a-text-file-which-is-being-written-on-by-another#comment36087067_23523139) you would likely be better off to exchange the data between the different operations without touching a file. For example, you could use a FIFO, linked list, or other such memory. If you need logging to a file, you could write to files as data is pushed into or out of the memory element.

Not understanding your full problem, you could also consider generating packets to be read by your testbench, external to your testbench, with a tool more appropriate to the task, such as Python or Perl.